# Download file using JQuery/Php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, file

I want to download a file returned by a php page when invoked by a jquery event. I red that inserting an `<iframe>` could do the trick, but It says on w3school that this tag is deprecated. I wonder if there's any other solution.

I think it might be relevent to say that the event that trigger the download is a button from a modal window using simple-modal. I want keep that window opened after the event.

It's the first time I'm downloading file with PHP so there might be an easy way to achieve this that i'm unaware of.

Comment: why not just redirect your user to the download url, you could even use target="_blank" to make sure the download opens in a new window/tab, and since the link is just the file url, then the window/tab will immediately close itself

Comment: I used php cause I need to controle who have access to which files. And the way I design it, I feel it suits better to just click download and it starts downloading than beign redirected.

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: haha.. thanks Marc B to open my eyes on w3school. I really thought that was reliable source.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an alternate php file that will force download when you click the button. Use headers in php
this might help :
[headers](http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download)

Comment: Yes thanks, that the solution I was trying to implement, but since I need to use an iframe with this method to keep the user at the same page, I wanted to be sure.

Comment: you can try calling that php file via $.get or $.post sending some trigger param ,and i think it wouldn't lead to open another page.

Comment: Not sure if I'm right, but $.get and $.post expect to received html content and not a header... but will try it more exhaustively

Answer (score 0):

You may use PHP to redirect to the file under certain permissions.

```
<?php
    if($username == "soandso") {
        header("Location: download.exe");
    }
?>
```

Also, the `<iframe>` tag is not deprecated. Still works for old and new browsers.

Comment: By download a file I want it to start the download... like in chrome it start the download at the bottom of the screen. It know it is alive and it works, but it's mentionned to be deprecated on w3school. So I was wondering if there's another "clean" solution that is not using a deprecated tag.

Comment: PHP is a server-side programming language. It cannot force the client to download a file. All it can do is redirect to it, where the browser will download it and bring it back to the previous page.

Comment: Ok thanks for to clarify things, but how this solution will works using ajax calls with jquery?